Psychology of innovation
In the arts, I think there is a connection between inventiveness and egotism.
There is an inherent attraction to doing something that no one has done before, especially when it seems like a good idea.
Sometimes, innovative people can be quite protective of their ideas. Even for people where it does not seem that public adulation is a primary interest of theirs, there are anecdotes of how when a great idea is in reach, people can become emotionally invested in a great idea on a personal level. I am thinking of Albert Einstein and also Andrew Wiles, both cases where there are anecdotes of people racing to publish results on a new discovery before anyone else does.
It seems like in some ways, it can be hard to take the ego out of the desire to innovate. No human is completely ego-less.
I’m interested in an analysis from any sort of humanistic philosophy or psychology for if there should be any reason that you can’t authentically separate a deep drive to innovate from the need to associate your own identity with what you create.
In other words, imagine that you feel you have a bold new idea. Of course, you can share it with others before you’ve had the time to develop it yourself and present it in final form. But should you? Should you want to?
I can think of examples of musical composers who are explicitly deterred from an idea simply because they know somebody already did it.
Is there some reason why innovation has to be driven by a psychology which has an egoic need to differentiate itself from others?

There is a nascent philosophical field that explores this sort of question. Amy Kind is one such philosopher who works on imagination. The SEP has both an article on Creativity and Imagination. I suspect there are many sources of imaginative creativity: love, war, commerce, ego, etc. Kind has a book on the topic.

The rationale for granting intellectual property rights under the US Constitution is to promote progress in science and the useful arts. That seems like the capitalist thing to do: to allocate rights to intellectual property in the short run which promotes progress in science and the useful arts for the public in the long run.
https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/intellectual_property_clause

The Intellectual Property (IP) Clause, also known as the “Patent and Copyright Clause” refers to Article I, Section 8, Clause 8 of the United States Constitution, which grants Congress the enumerated power "To promote the progress of science and useful arts, by securing for limited times to authors and inventors the exclusive right to their respective writings and discoveries." It is a foundational document establishing intellectual property rights in the United States, replacing the patchwork of state-law protections that existed in the Articles of Confederation period.


This clause gave Congress the power to enact legislation governing patents and copyrights. For patents, the clause gave Congress the power to grant inventors exclusive rights to their discoveries, allowing inventors to recoup their investment, and capitalize on their research.


For copyrights, the clause gave Congress the power to grant authors exclusive rights over their writings. In subsequent federal legislation, such as the US Copyright Act (codified at 17 U.S.C. §§ 101 - 810), the meaning of “writings” has expanded, now encompassing a wide range of artistic and intellectual works, from movies to software.


The utilitarian aim of the Intellectual Property Clause is to maximize scientific and artistic progress. It does so by attempting to balance the incentives it provides for innovation, against the chilling effects that limiting access to writings and discoveries may have on novel thought.

Historically Galileo, and other applied scholars and artists, sought fame via publication or promoting authorship; but also sought to gain economic and political resources from Patrons in governing and/or wealthy families. One could gain money and status by taking credit for progress in science or authoring works of art.
Sigmund Freud argued that the ego, the effort to govern action, includes the development of the superego consisting of the observer, the ego ideal, and the conscience. The observation of behavior of self and others is the function of the observer. The ego ideal is what a child develops when observing the roles of adults and peers; the type of ego that is ideal. The conscience is supposed to be about offense against the rules of society, and the sense of guilt, of right and wrong conduct, etc. Somewhere in the formation of the ego ideal and the conscience would be the psychology of human status seeking. Freud argued that abolishing private property would not of itself be sufficient to eliminate human aggression and social conflict from the socialist or communist society.
In my judgment there are people who enjoy playing status games, and there are people with social anxiety, often linked to their pain or fear evoked by these status games. I think the roots of the desire for status are in what Freud calls the ego ideal (Jesus was tempted by Satan via the infantile ideas of male power, status, and rulership in this world).
Kevin Simler maps human status seeking behavior to the animal world of Dominance-Prestige hierarchy:
https://meltingasphalt.com/social-status-down-the-rabbit-hole/
I think of humans as baboons with symboling minds. We learn to play status games in the context of symbolic drama during early life and then we persist those games during social interactions. Most people who pay for talk therapy most likely lost the dominance-prestige game in early life. People who want to be paid to provide talk therapy may or may not be effective "healers". They might just enjoy winning the dominance-prestige game with a person who submits to their authority as an expert on life and provides them with psychological transparency. Human motives are the most difficult thing to understand in part because we can only observe the behavior of others and draw an inference from the knowledge of our own motives in a variety of dramatic contexts.

Giving birth to a new idea and seeing it to fruition can be a painful process. It is only in anecdotes that a new and clever idea can get you somewhere. People in the field are not interested in ideas, they want meaningful results.
But to get from an idea to something more real will require budget, academic support, peer support, a lot of pushing, promoting and explaining.
And from a philosophical point of view, often, these people feel like the idea itself is not theirs. It was given to them by God or the Matrix and their purpose in life is to carry this idea to maturity.
